# Is this a reasonable way to initialise my library?

Tags: c++, initialization

I'm building a library (Foo) on top of a third party library (Bar) which requires an `Initialise()` free function to be called at the start of any program which uses it, and a `DeInitialise()` function at the end. I would like to "cascade" these function through to my library, so that the user is required to initialise mine, without needing to know anything about the third party library's initialisation. In addition, I can perform any other initialisation my library may require, in the same place. I could just use my third party library's approach using free functions e.g.:

```
namespace Foo
{
   Initialise()
   {
      Bar::Initialise();
      // Do rest of Foo's initialisation
   }
   DeInitialise()
   {
      Bar::DeInitialise();
      // Do rest of Foo's de-initialisation
   }
}
```

The user of Foo would then be required to call `Foo::Initialise` before using it and `Foo::DeInitialise` at the end, and has the responsibility to ensure that it is only called once (thus I can avoid worrying about thread safety issues).

This is the approach that I've mostly come across when searching for solutions to this problem. However I'm now considering placing all my initialisation and de-initialisation in the constructor / destructor of a class e.g.:

```
Class Initialiser
{
   Initialiser()
   {
      Bar::Initialise();
      // Do rest of Foo's initialisation
   }
   ~Initialiser()
   {
      Bar::DeInitialise();
      // Do rest of Foo's de-initialisation
   }
}
```

Thus freeing the user from having to worry about de-initilisation - they just create an `Initialiser` object on the stack at the start of their program, and the destructor will take care of the rest when the program exits.

My question is: is this a reasonable approach? Are there any potential pitfalls or alternative solutions to consider? Is it even valid to have a class with only a constructor and a destructor but no data members?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have come up with is infact called [RAII - Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), and is core a design concept to programming in C++ OOP. It makes the code exception safe and spares the user from needing to manually calling the functions.

This is the correct way of doing what you want done, as long as you don't have complications such as virtual function calls in your constructor/destructor.

Comment: Thanks. As for my final question then - is it valid to have a class with a ctor/dtor but no data members?

Comment: @JBentley: Yes, it is perfectly valid.

Comment: @JBentley depends on what you mean by valid. It is 100% valid from C++ POV, slightly wierd from design POV, understandable if it is primarily a RAII wrapper for your other library. Ensure your member functions are not `static`, to force your user to make an object.